# Cannot view post images from iOS app

Tags: bug, ios-app

Viewing a Stack Exchange post in the iOS app on my iPhone 6s, I cannot view an image automatically nor by clicking it.

It instead says:

> enter image description here

- App Version: 1.6.6.2
- Device: iPhone 6s
- OS Version: Version 13.1.3 (Build 17A878)

link to question:
https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/66843/36828

[image: cant open the image]